# Wordpress Query Multiple Custom Fields Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a custom Wordpress query and is querying 2 custom fields and it is not working.  If I use 1 of the query parameters it works, for both of the query parameters so it seems obvious that it is the way I am combining the queries.

```
$query_args_paged = array(
        'post_type'                   =>    'product',
        'paged'                       =>    1,
        'posts_per_page'              =>    -1,
        'post_status'                 =>    'publish',
        'orderby'                     =>    'ID',
        'order'                       =>    'desc',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'meta_key'      =>  'ea_gs_job_status',
                'meta_value'    =>  'finished',
                'meta_compare'  =>  '=',
            ),
            array(
                'meta_key'      =>  'ea_gs_ad_rank',
                'meta_value'    =>  1,
                'meta_compare'  =>  '=',
            ),
        ),
    );
```

Comment: seems right to me, did you make sure you have posts that match job_status finished and ad_rank 1?

Comment: Are you sure that you are storing an INTEGER in the database? And not a string (or a real boolean maybe, idk if WP would see the difference between 1/0 INT and a boolean)? You could test adding a `'type' => 'NUMERIC',` to your `meta_query`. Check [this stack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108485/meta-query-with-boolean-true-false-value)